# ERROR: In exporting mysqli query results into excel using php

Tags: php, excel, mysqli

I am trying to export `MySQL` query results into excel. Therefore I wrote the following `PHP` script:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','xyz','abc');
$select = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
$export = mysqli_query( $conn,$select) or die ( "Sql error : " . 
mysqli_error($conn) );
$fields = mysqli_num_rows ( $export );
for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
{
//But this line giving error continuously 
$header .= mysqli_fetch_field_direct($export,$i) . "\t";
 }
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_row( $export ) )
{
 $line = '';
 foreach( $row as $value )
 {
  if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
  {
    $value = "\t";
  }
  else
  {
     $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
     $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
  }
  $line .= $value;
 }
$data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
 }
$data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );
if ( $data == "" )
{
  $data = "\n(0) Records Found!\n";
}
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=random.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print "$header\n$data";
```

But I am getting this error:

```
PHP Recoverable fatal error:  
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in this line
$header .= mysqli_fetch_field_direct($export,$i) . "\t";
```

and now I'm facing problem in debugging this code.

Answer (score 1):

Look to description and examples.

This **mysqli_fetch_field_direct** returns an object

Or try **typecasting** : **(string)mysqli_fetch_field_direct($export,$i)**

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field-direct.php

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my problem,instead of doing this `$header .= mysqli_fetch_field_direct($export,$i) . "\t";` now i am using `$header .= mysqli_fetch_field_direct($export,$i)->name . "\t";`.
Now Its working fine.